# Convert Days to Year,Month,Day Format

Tags: php

I have this problem. Can someone help me,how to convert number of days into the format XX Years, XX Month, XX Days...
i created this function,

```
function convert($sum) {
    $years = ($sum / 365) ;
    $years = floor($years); 
    $month = ($sum % 365) / 30.5; 
    $month = floor($month); 
    $days = ($sum % 365) % 30.5; // the rest of days
    // Echo all information set
    echo 'DAYS RECEIVE : '.$sum.' days<br>';
    echo $years.' years - '.$month.' month - '.$days.' days';
}

convert(151);
```

But with **151** days  the result was wrong

> DAYS RECEIVE : 151 days
> 0 years - 4 month - 1 days

it must be 4 month ans 28 days not 1 day...

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5e6b4b4f6a27024b66ffbf04e80698722a3ecab

Comment: You're making some big assumptions about how many days there are in a month.

Comment: And if you want to use mod with a float, then use fmod()

Comment: / 30.5; // I choose 30.5 for Month (30,31) ;)

Comment: I saw what you chose, I've also commented on the value

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): `Operands of modulo are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing. For floating-point modulo, see fmod().`... so you're not actually using 30.5, you're using 30 when you calculate the days

Comment: Well having to use fmod is a disappointment for me from PHP...

Comment: Well I'm sorry that you find PHP so disappointing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use more modern PHP, the following is based around actual days in each month:

```
$days = 151;

$start_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = (new $start_date)->add(new DateInterval("P{$days}D") );
$dd = date_diff($start_date,$end_date);
echo $dd->y." years ".$dd->m." months ".$dd->d." days";
```

Note that it will vary, depending on the current date, so you might prefer to set `$start_date` and `$end_date` to work from a fixed baseline

```
$days = 151;

$start_date = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
$end_date = (new DateTime('1970-01-01'))->add(new DateInterval("P{$days}D") );
$dd = date_diff($start_date,$end_date);
echo $dd->y." years ".$dd->m." months ".$dd->d." days";
```

Comment: Will break every 5 years. It's only valid until 28 of February. Then it might be 29 Februari or the 1st of March

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your problem:

```
function convert($sum) {
    $years = floor($sum / 365);
    $months = floor(($sum - ($years * 365))/30.5);
    $days = ($sum - ($years * 365) - ($months * 30.5));
    echo “Days received: ” . $sum . “ days <br />”;
    echo $years . “ years, “ . $months . “months, “ . $days . “days”;
}
```