# Given the number of days in PHP, how do I calculate years, months, and days from it?

Tags: php, date, format, days

I am storing days in a Mysql database, and I am trying to format those days in a year, month, days format. My variable that stores the days is called `$days`

Here is what I have:

```
$years = ($days / 365);
$years = floor($years);

$month = ($days % 365) / 30.5;
$month = floor($month);

$days = ($days % 365) % 30.5;

$display = "$years" . " years, " . "$month" . " months, and " . "$days" . " days";
```

However, whenever I have my days to a value such as 90, it just displays as 2 months, and doesn't show anything for the days, just 2 months. I found this online somewhere, and it was working nicely until recently.

Can anyone give me some pointers on a better way to do this, or with any errors in my code?

Comment: $days is just days. For example, it can be just "90". It is only a numerical representation of a number of days.

Comment: Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762461/1456401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
<?php
  $days = '365';
  $start_date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d"));
  $end_date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d",strtotime("+$days days")));
  $dd = date_diff($start_date,$end_date);
  echo "$dd->y year(s) $dd->m month(s) $dd->d day(s)";
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/918854  AND  https://eval.in/918858

Answer (score 0):

As there is no certain date specified, You can do this way

```
<?php
$days = 500;
$years = intval($days / 365); 
$days = $days % 365;

$months = intval($days / 30); 
$days = $days % 30;

echo "$years years, $months months, $days days";

?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/918861

Output will be like  : `1 years, 4 months, 15 days`